# How to find string that is not set in xml in android studio？

Tags: android, android-studio, multilingual

My project needs to support multilingual functions.

But some strings are not set to the xml file, I need to search for these strings.
These strings may appear in xml layout files or java, kt files.

Does android studio have tools or recommended plug-ins that can speed up the completion of the work?
Thanks for help

Comment: You can right click on the module -> Find in path -> Use a regex -> `".*"`

Comment: On Mac: Command+shift+F and type your string you will find in the whole project,
For Windows Ctrl+shift+F

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.The tool I want is to find specific text that is not placed in the xml file, such as displaying "Hardcoded string "aaa:", should use @string resource".

Answer (score 1):

You can find the strings hardcoded in the layout files with the following regexp:
`android:text="[^@]`

[image]

and in the kotlin files with this (it might not cover all the cases but you get the point): `setMessage\("|setTitle\("|setText\("|text ?= ?"`

[image]